# Direct2D Direct3d11 interop - can device be lost?

Tags: directx, direct2d, direct3d11

In my app I'm using direct2d to write to a shared (d3d11/d3d10) texture. This is the only kind of render target that is used in my app. Since devices can be lost in direct2d (D2DERR_RECREATE_RENDER_TARGET), lots of code exists to abstract and/or recreate device dependent resources. However, I have yet to see this situation actually occur, and am curious whether I am wasting effort. Can the render target actually be lost in this scenario, or am I protected since the texture is created via d3d11 (though shared with d3d10)? If so, does anyone know a reproducible, simple way to cause the render target to be lost so I can at least test the code that handles this condition?

Comment: have you tried to change desktop resolution?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but yes - and render target was still not lost. I've also tried switching from full screen to windowed, resizing window, and locking/unlocking desktop.

Comment: Sent PC to sleep/hybernate maybe?

Comment: wow - neither sleep nor even hibernate result in a lost render target.

Comment: That is simply awesome! Driver writers have really overcome themselves since dx8 when it was enough as I recall to just alt-tab from a fullscreen app to loose all of the device! I'm just out of ideas what else could be done when a driver can handle sleep/hibernate. Can it survive PC shutdown?;)

Comment: Got two more - detaching a secondary monitor and device driver update.

Comment: Don't forget about accessing the app via Remote Desktop / Terminal Services.

Answer (score 4):

It’s not a wasted effort. Many scenarios may cause device loss to occur. A simple way to induce this for testing purposes is to update your graphics driver. Your application should handle this gracefully. It can also happen behind the scenes if your graphics driver crashes or Windows Update installs a new version in the background. There are other cases but those are probably the most common.

You can use the Device Manager to roll back and update your driver quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A D2D window render target will always be lost when another program uses any version of the D3D API to go fullscreen and back (exclusive mode, not the new windowed mode supported since D3D10/11). In D3D11, I think you have to cause a resolution change for the D2D render target to be lost.

So if you do not get the D2DERR_RECREATE_RENDER_TARGET HRESULT in this case, when Presenting to your texture render target, then maybe you do not need to re-create the render target, but I would still handle D2DERR_RECREATE_RENDER_TARGET. To test it, you could just replace the texture render target with a window render target during development.